# alternate mongo aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregate mongodb query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {a: "a1", b: "b1"}},{$group: {...}}, 
    {$sort: {...}}, {$limit: {10}}
])
```

I have a compound index on a and b, and the query is fast.

However when I change the match to

```
 $match: {$or: [{a: "a1", b: "b1"}, {a: "a2", b: "b2"}]}
```

the query becomes quite slow and it doesn't seem to use any indices.

Is there any way to either 1) Rewrite the query to use the compound index (as a single query) or 2) Force it to use the index?

Comment: if you defined **db.coll.createIndex({a : 1, b: 1})** , your query will use the compound index properly

Comment: I thought so but thats not what it tells me with explain. It is not using the index with the $or but it does without.

Comment: Can you post the `explain` results of your query and modify your code to include on what fields you perform the `sort` operation.

Comment: Because I got asked about this, I can say that I don't see a degradation over 1,000,000 operations in a simple test so it would be interesting to see the result size. True the "explain" plan from aggregate does not clearly say an index is used. However I don't see a performance degrade to suggest it is not being used. So for me it's quite fast. Without making us trawl the code, can you post some metrics for your difference in your question please?

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB server are you using? Can you also include the output of `db.collection.find(...).explain(true)` so we can see the query plans considered for your `$or` query?

Comment: The version is 2.6.1. I am sorting descending just on the total field since all I want is the top counts of the grouping. I don't have any index therefore on the sort stage.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding a sort step to the beginning of the aggregation to see if it forces the use of your index.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$sort: {a:1, b:1}},
    {$match: {$or: [{a: "a1", b: "b1"}, {a: "a2", b: "b2"}]}},
    ...
])
```

Comment: While placing $sort at the beginning of the pipeline might influence the selected index, it certainly is not the result you want. The aggregation pipeline is only capable of accessing the index in the very first stage, so any subsequent stage cannot use the index and the benefits of using index bounds are lost. `$match` should almost always be the first stage of any aggregation pipeline.

Comment: @Neil-Lunn, nice to know about the indexing and the $match, but why the indexing in the question does not work properly?

Comment: @Disposer Honestly don't know and will probably be trawling code tom morrow to find out why.This is not the way to solve it and that is all I was tagging..

Comment: @NeilLunn In MongoDB 2.6 there's a [`$sort` + `$match` sequence optimisation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#sort-match-sequence-optimization) so the order may be moot if those are the first two operations in the pipeline. Need to know server version and candidate indexes to narrow down the surface area for an answer ;)

Comment: @Stennie whilst that is "listed" as an optimization it only moves the `$match` before the `$sort`, hence really a "code correction" and comes back to the point I was making. As for the server version the OP quotes "but that's not what it tells me with explain", So it's reasonable to say 2.6.x even though I believe the explain option was present in 2.4.9 but undocumented. So I don't think most people even tried on an earlier version. But could be wrong there.

Comment: @NeilLunn: my comment was in response to your mention of aggregation only accessing an index in the first stage and that `$match` should almost always be first. Since pipeline steps can be re-ordered in 2.6, that assertion is no longer true from a usage point of view. If the server adjusts your pipeline to be more efficient that certainly seems like an "optimisation" rather than a "code correction".

Comment: @Stennie Couldn't disagree more and I am trying to point out good practice rather than needing "other code" to correct the order of statements to what they should have been. Indexes cannot be used once documents are not modified in a pipeline so that should not be made ambiguous by other statements. Anyhow this is wildly off-topic. The "Answer" here would not help the situation described by the OP and should not be adopted by anyone as a practiced method. That is the purpose of my comment here.